# Odoo - Update record when click on button in email template

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I am using Odoo 10-e. I create a simple email template which i am sending on a particular event from my class. What i want to know that is this possible in Odoo to create a email template and put button into it. When user click on that button my particular class field will be updated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Edit your question with your efforts, code, error log, etc.

Comment: How would you do something when you don't even know that its possible or not . Well i have created email template placed button in that template. Already written code for sending email. But at this stage i don't know how to update python class on click of a button in email

Comment: What kind of updation you want in python class ?

Comment: I need to update that class property may be set that to True

Answer (score 1):

You could write a [http controller](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/http.html) which will update a database record. Just let the "email button" call a specific url.

**But keep in mind that giving non odoo users (and that's what you're doing here) such access rights could end in a security disaster.**

Comment: Is this safe if am sending that email to odoo users. I mean if the receiving user belongs to Odoo then any other approach exists or not ?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I'm not that deep into the topic :-/

Comment: Can you reference any example here how can i access my model class in http controller ?

Comment: [Odoo mail module](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/mail/controllers/main.py) should have enough examples.